# Largest n digit octal number

Tags: sequences-and-series

What will be the largest n digit octal number.

I think

$$\text{ for } n = 1 , \text{ans} = 7$$
$$\text{ for } n = 2 , \text{ans} = 77$$
$$\text{ for } n = 3 , \text{ans} = 777$$

So am I correct ?

And it's general ans will be $$\frac{7.10^n - 1}{9}$$

I just want to know that if i am making correct formula or not?

Comment: Given any base $k>1$, the largest number you can express with $n$ digits is $k^n-1$.

Comment: You are evaluating it as if were decimal instead of  octal.  $77$ in octal is $63$ in decimal.

Comment: When you write a number in a base other than $10$, you should use a notation that indicates the base.  For $n = 2$, the largest two-digit octal number is $77_8 = 7 \cdot 8 + 7 = 5 + 7 = 63 = 8^2 - 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The largest $3$-digit octal number is indeed $777$, but only if this is interpreted as base $8$. To make this explicit, we can write it as $777_8$.

So the largest $3$-digit octal number is
$$777_8 = 7 \times 64_{10}+7\times 8 + 7 = 511_{10}$$

This is not the same as $7\times (10^3-1)/9=777_{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**  What is the largest digit in Octal base system ? How can you use it to form the biggest number in octal system of $n$ digits ? How can you convert it into decimal representation ??

Clue :  $$(XYZ)_8 = (X \times8^2+Y \times8^1+Z \times8^0)_{10}$$